# PowerBI report for handling events and registrations for those events

Tags: powerbi, pivot

Another PowerBI question: I have three tables dealing with people signing up for events:

**Event**

```
EventId (PK)
Event Name
Event Date
```

**EventRegistration**

```
EventRegistrationId (PK)
EventId (FK to Event)
Registration Date
First Name
Last Name
E-Mail
```

**EventRegistrationAnswers**

```
ID (PK)
Event Registration (FK to EventRegistration)
Field Name
Value
```

The thing is: the event registration happens based on a web form, and the event manager can design that form at will, and can include pretty much any kind of question to ask the person signing up, so the `EventRegistrationAnswers` table may contain any number of answers (given at signup), and for each event, that might be different.

So for an event registration with Id=4711, I might have answers like this - some are free text fields, some are values picked from a dropdown list, some are Yes/No checkboxes:

| Id | EventRegistrationId | Field Name | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 4711 | Salutation | Mister |
| 124 | 4711 | OK to store data | Yes |
| 125 | 4711 | Signup for newsletter | No |
| 126 | 4711 | Arrival | By public transport |

My task is this:

- People organising events would like to choose their event from a list (that's handled by a slicer, based on the `Event` table - works fine)
- They would then like to see all registrations for that event, including all the answers given on the signup form

I tried to apply a "Pivot Column" operation to the "Event Registration Answers" table, which converts the data into a table with columns names based on the "Field Name" column of the original table - so far - so good. **BUT** this also converts the data into one row for each answer given - so for a single registration, I get one row per answer given in which one column has a value - something like this:

| EventRegistrationId | Salutation | OK to store data | Signup for newsletter | Arrival |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4711 | Mister | *(NULL)* | *(NULL)* | *(NULL)* |
| 4711 | *(NULL)* | Yes | *(NULL)* | *(NULL)* |
| 4711 | *(NULL)* | *(NULL)* | No | *(NULL)* |
| 4711 | *(NULL)* | *(NULL)* | *(NULL)* | By public transport |

Now if I merge the `EventRegistration` table to this pivoted table, based on the `EventRegistrationId`, I get multiple rows for each registration - while I'd really like to have a **single row** for each registration, with all four columns providing their respective (*non-NULL*) value.

Any ideas how I can do that?? Somehow it seems I cannot really influence the "PIVOT COLUMN" operation a whole lot ..... and I haven't found a way to "condense" those four rows - with only one column each filled with a value - into a single row where all columns would have a non-NULL value.... (I looked at `GROUP BY` and others, but nothing seemed to fit my bill)

Any ideas?

Comment: Probably best to keep it as it is (unpivoted). Why do you want it to be pivoted and/or to merge?

Comment: @SamNseir: well, the stakeholders would love to have a "flat list" of all registrations with all additional values provided as answers, so that they can export that flat list into Excel and mess around with it some more ;-)

Comment: What would the flat list look like? Say there are 5 different events, and each have 5 different questions, do you want to see 25 columns for the answers?

Comment: @SamNseir: well yes - that would be the consequence - I'm trying hard to get them to accept the three levels - Event, Registrations, Answers - but sometimes business people with an Excel head can be pretty stubborn .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you pivot `EventRegistrationAnswers`, drop/remove the `Id` column.

[image]

```
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(Source,{"Id"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Columns", List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns"[#"Field Name"]), "Field Name", "Value")
```

Comment: Again - so easy once you know it ;-) Thanks a heap - again !